# Magento 2.2.5 - Backups User Roles Permission

Tags: magento-2.2.5, permissions, user-roles, backup

I'm using Magento 2.2.5.

Steps to reproduce:

1. System -> Permission -> User Roles
2. Backups

   > Sorry, you need permissions to view this content

How to fix it?

Comment: are you logged in as administrator Or other user ?

Comment: Other user . I already give Permission but can't still and system menu showing Client&IPN too @Pawan

Comment: @Pawan can you help?